# Anyway to merge multiple cells and reorganize in excel?

Tags: excel, graph, graphics, datamodel

First of all sorry for my English, I will try my best to explain myself

I add a screen of what I need if it can help

[image: Screen]

I'm currently trying to create a graph with many data in excel but currently I only find a easy way to reformat my excel to make it work.

I would like to know if it's possible to make excel do my work for all the data :D

Quick example of what I have and what I need

For now I have multiple occurrence of 4 computer names like :

```
Computer1
Computer2
Computer3
Computer4
```

I have some date for the whole year like :

```
2021-01-01
2021-01-02
2021-01-02
etc
```

And I have a columns with data in it for each computer and each day like :

```
Computer 1 | 2021-01-01 | 500
Computer 2 | 2021-01-01 | 300
Computer 3 | 2021-01-01 | 200
Computer 4 | 2021-01-01 | 800
Computer 1 | 2021-01-02 |1000
Computer 2 | 2021-01-02 | 480
Computer 3 | 2021-01-02 | 356
Computer 4 | 2021-01-02 | 154
```

What I would like to do is to set something like :

```
            Computer 1 | Computer 2 | Computer 3 | Computer 4
2021-01-01         500 |        300 |        200 |        800
2021-01-02        1000 |        480 |        356 |        154
```

If you want any additional information or i didn't explain myself right, don't hesitate !

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Use a Pivot Table/Pivot Chart.  It will do what you want in a few steps.

Comment: @Neakath, Is my answer not acceptable? If answer brought you to a solution please check it.

Answer (score 0):

In excel there are the formulas for doing this like vlookup() and index(match()) but I don't recommend formulas. You can also create a pivot table. In excel there is the power query option. I recommend the use power query to do a merge of the different data, transform, and transpose the data.

1. Create the table (**Ctrl**+**t**). When you enter data into the next row the table will auto expand.
2. Go to Data> From Table/ Range.
   [image]
3. There are 2 option you can close and load to pivot table or as shown you can transform>Pivot Column.
   [image]
4. select the values column (amount) after making selection hit **OK**
   [image]
5. click on file and Close and load.
6. After making additional changes hit the **Refresh** button under **Data**